# How to create a heatmap from list of coordinates?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of coordinates in form `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}`

Is there a way in mma to builds density plots based on position (
`ListDensityPlot` calculates density based on value in `{x,y,value}`)? I want to create something similar to [heatmap.py](http://jjguy.com/heatmap/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two functions that can do this:

- [`DensityHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DensityHistogram.html?q=DensityHistogram&lang=en)
- [`Histogram3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram3D.html?q=Histogram3D&lang=en)

These functions also come in a smoothed version (prepend `Smooth` to the name), which can be used to obtain results similar to what Heike plotted.

**Edit**

If you work in a regime where individual points are resolved, you may notice a disconcerting shift in the output of `SmoothDensityHistogram` (at least I see it on Mac OS X, MMA version 8.0.4):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
Show[
 SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 0.015, "PDF",
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Mesh -> 0,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
 Graphics[Point@data],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
 ]
```

[image: ShiftedDensity]

I only noticed this after looking at R.M.'s plot with the original points superimposed, as shown above.

To fix this and at the same time understand better what these smoothed histogram plots really do, you could take a look at the following function:

```
heatMap[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {n, size, xRange, pr},
  n = "Points" /. {opts} /. {"Points" -> 100};
  pr = PlotRange /. {opts} /. {PlotRange :> 
      Map[{Min[#], Max[#]} &, Transpose[data]]};
  xRange = -Subtract @@ pr[[1]];
  size = Floor[
    n ("Radius" /. {opts} /. {"Radius" -> xRange/6})/xRange];
  Graphics[{
    Inset[
     ArrayPlot[
      Rescale@GaussianFilter[
        ImageData@ColorNegate@ColorConvert[
           Rasterize[Graphics[Point[data],
             Background -> White,
             PlotRangePadding -> 0,
             ImagePadding -> 0,
             ImageMargins -> 0,
             PlotRange -> pr],
            "Image", ImageSize -> n], "GrayScale"],
        {3 size, size}, Padding -> 0],
      ColorFunction ->  
       (ColorFunction /. {opts} /. 
        {ColorFunction -> 
         ColorData["LakeColors"]
        }
       ),
      ImagePadding -> 0,
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False],
     pr[[All, 1]], {0, 0}, xRange]},
   PlotRange -> pr, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]
   ]
  ]

Show[heatMap[data, "Points" -> 300, "Radius" -> .02, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"]],
 Graphics[Point@data], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: noSHift]

So I basically re-implemented this plotting function by using `GaussianFilter`, without trying to implement all the options provided by the built-in function.

The options it recognizes are `"Points"` (the number of sampling points in the horizontal direction), `"Radius"` (the radius of the Gaussian) and `PlotRange`.

Besides giving better alignment between the heat map and the points, this manual approach also could be used to do some non-standard things. For example, you could change `Padding -> 0` to `Padding -> "Periodic"` if the data points live on a torus topology.

To show the dependence on the choice of radius, here is a movie:

```
Export["l.gif", 
 Join[#, Reverse[#]] &@
  Table[Show[
    heatMap[data, "Points" -> 300, "Radius" -> r^2, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], Graphics[Point@data], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
   {r, .15, .25, .015}], "DisplayDurations" -> .1]
```

[image: snoothing]

**Edit**

I forgot to add `ColorFunction` as an option - that's now done, with `"LakeColors"` as the default, as it is for `SmoothDensityHistogram`. There was also a `Frame -> False` missing in `ArrayPlot`, which I fixed in the code.

As an added bonus, plots created with `heatMap` take much less space when exported as `PDF`.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [SmoothDensityHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothDensityHistogram.html) to generate heatmaps. This does the same as what Heike's method does, but in one line. Example:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 0.02, "PDF", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I modified the ColorFunction to `(If[# <= 0.0624, White, 
    ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][440 + 240*#]] &)` to make it look more like heatmap.py

Comment: @R.M. Do you also see an offset between the maxima and the original points if you plot them together? I see that on my machine, see my answer. It seems to indicate that someone was sloppy when writing this function.

Comment: @Jens Yes, it shows up on mine and Heike's too. Looks like `SmoothKernelDistribution` is the culprit (since `SDH` calls `SKD` internally). I did notice a spurious offset in a more involved example I was working on that included image processing, but I didn't realize it was due to `SKD` and instead thought it was due to some sloppy `Dilation`s on my part... Thanks for pointing this out. Probably should send an email to `support@wolfram` too...

Comment: I've sent a bug report about `SmoothDensityHistogram` to Wolfram [TS 21354].

Comment: @Jens This is a case where boosting `InterpolationPoints` to say 256 will be useful. It is more of a failure of automation than a bug. `KernelMixtureDistribution` might be a better alternative though.

Comment: @Andy `SmoothDensityHistogram` does not have the `InterpolationPoints` option (at least in version 8.0.4). What did you mean?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I believe it actually does have this option it just isn't documented. It certainly seems to have an effect for me.

Comment: @Andy It appears in red but it works. Thank you!

Comment: I think that the problem is this "For multivariate densities, the kernel function ker can be specified as product and radial types using {"Product",ker} and {"Radial",ker} respectively. Product-type kernels are used if no type is specified". You have to choose it Radial for get points centered.

Answer (score 18):

It looks like [SmoothKernelDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) might do the trick. For example

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];

dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, .02]

DensityPlot[Evaluate[PDF[dist, {x, y}]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]