# One-dimensional heatmap

Tags: visualization

I want to plot a heatmap of a set of real points of the interval [0,1] - i.e., to display their linear density in the sense of a smoothed histogram. The idea I have come up so far is to use the heatMap function introduced [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6081/how-to-create-a-heatmap-from-list-of-coordinates):

```
heatMap[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
{n, size, xRange, pr},
n = "Points" /. {opts} /. {"Points" -> 100};
pr = PlotRange /. {opts} /. {PlotRange :> 
    Map[{Min[#], Max[#]} &, Transpose[data]]};
xRange = -Subtract @@ pr[[1]];
size = Floor[
  n ("Radius" /. {opts} /. {"Radius" -> xRange/6})/xRange];
Graphics[{
  Inset[
   ArrayPlot[
    Rescale@GaussianFilter[
      ImageData@ColorNegate@ColorConvert[
         Rasterize[Graphics[Point[data],
           Background -> White,
           PlotRangePadding -> 0,
           ImagePadding -> 0,
           ImageMargins -> 0,
           PlotRange -> pr],
          "Image", ImageSize -> n], "GrayScale"],
      {3 size, size}, Padding -> 0],
    ColorFunction ->  
     (ColorFunction /. {opts} /. 
      {ColorFunction -> 
       ColorData["LakeColors"]
      }
     ),
    ImagePadding -> 0,
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False],
   pr[[All, 1]], {0, 0}, xRange]},
 PlotRange -> pr, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]
 ]
]
```

and converting the one dimensional data to two dimensions:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
data = {#, 0} & /@ data;

heatMap[data, "Points" -> 300, "Radius" -> .01, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, .05}}]
```

[image: sample plot]

How do I have to modify heatMap to draw rectangles instead of points that blur at the edges? Or perhaps is there a shorter and more elegant way to draw a "heatline"?

Comment: Sorry I simply had no time to reply until now - but since you mentioned my `heatMap` function I posted a modified version of it that should hopefully do what you want - or at least the needed modifications can be made easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like none of the answers I see up to now are actually producing heat maps. The difference between a heat map and a `ListDensityPlot` is important. In *Mathematica* vocabulary, the heat map is a `SmoothDensityHistogram`.

First of all, I tried to *directly* use the 'heatMap' function in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6082/245). I just tried it with the data in that post:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];

Show[heatMap[data, "Points" -> 300, "Radius" -> {10, .02}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"]], Graphics[Point@data], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: smearedsquare]

All I did is to specify a *tuple* `{10, .02}` for the `"Radius"` option. Its first entry is the radius in the vertical direction, and with a choice of `10` this smears all the data out over the entire vertical image range.

This shows it works without modifying the code. But of course I have to tweak the function in order to make it look more "one-dimensional":

```
heatMap[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{n, size, xRange, pr}, 
  n = "Points" /. {opts} /. {"Points" -> 100};
  pr = PlotRange /. {opts} /. {PlotRange :> 
      Map[{Min[#], Max[#]} &, Transpose[data]]};
  xRange = -Subtract @@ pr[[1]];
  size = Floor[
    n ("Radius" /. {opts} /. {"Radius" -> xRange/6})/xRange];
  Graphics[
   {Inset[
     ArrayPlot[
      Rescale@GaussianFilter[
        ImageData@ColorNegate@ColorConvert[
           Rasterize[
            Graphics[
             Point[data],
             Background -> White,
             PlotRangePadding -> 0,
             ImagePadding -> 0,
             ImageMargins -> 0,
             PlotRange -> pr
             ],
            "Image",
            ImageSize -> n
            ],
           "GrayScale"
           ],
        {3 size, size},
        Padding -> 0
        ],
      ColorFunction -> (ColorFunction /. {opts} /. {ColorFunction -> 
           ColorData["LakeColors"]}),
      ImagePadding -> 0,
      PlotRangePadding -> 0,
      Frame -> False
      ],
     pr[[All, 1]],
     {0, 0}, xRange]},
   PlotRange -> pr,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None}
   ]
  ]
```

So here I removed the `PlotRangePadding` and the `FrameTicks` on the left side, as well as the `PlotRangePadding`. I think that's all you need to change. Having collapsed the `data` onto a single axis, the vertical smearing for `GaussianFilter` needs to be only of order `1` (in relation to the horizontal axis) - so that's what I used. Then I set the `PlotRange` appropriately and get this:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
data = {#, 0} & /@ data;

heatMap[data, "Points" -> 300, "Radius" -> {1, .02}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, .04}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameLabel -> None]
```

[image: heatmapThin]

The meaning of the option `"Points"` (number of horizontal sampling points) is the same as described in the linked post.

**Edit**

As I mentioned, a heat map is also realizable using built-in smoothed histogram techniques. I think the easiest way to do that in the present case would be as follows:

```
DensityPlot[
 Evaluate@PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data, {1, .02}], {y, x}], {x, 
  0, 1}, {y, 0, .2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> {200, 2},
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image: heatmapDensityPlot]

The unequal smearing is now achieved by specifying a *tuple* for the "bandwidth" parameter in `SmoothKernelDistribution`: in `{1, .02}`, the `1` is again chosen to be large compared to the plot range in the `y` direction (from `0` to `.2`) so that you get vertical bands. It's of also necessary to adjust the number of `PlotPoints` to be large enough in the horizontal direction so as to capture all the details of the distribution. The vertical number of `PlotPoints` (the second number in `{200, 2}`) can be set to the smallest possible value, `2`.

**Edit 2**

Of course, we can also backtrack even further and go to the original data set you started with -  which was purely one-dimensional. In that situation, you can simply do something like this:

```
data = RandomReal[1, 100];

DensityPlot[
 Evaluate[{PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data, .02], x], 0}], {x, 0, 
  1}, {y, 0, .04}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> {200, 2}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image: No Smearing]

This involves *no* need for smearing in the vertical direction because it calculates the density function one-dimensionally in the first place. The methods above have their justification too, when the `data` list does have two-dimensional points that you want to project onto a single axis.

**Edit 3**

I also see the question asks for a "heatline" - if I understand this as a line plot, one could get it very straightforwardly:

```
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data, .02], x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: heatline]

This is simply a plot of the one-dimensional probability density function for the  data set, smoothed with bandwidth `.02`.

Comment: Jens, would you edit the question to include (a link to) the best concise description of a "heat map" you can find?  I'll profess my ignorance and say I didn't realize that was a specialized chart type.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The link in the question points to a pretty long post describing exactly what the term "heat map" is supposed to mean. So I would certainly not fault Frederic for neglecting to explain things. But I'll see if I can make a modest modification to clarify the concept.

Comment: I'm not faulting anyone but myself.

Comment: @Jens The result you plotted in Edit 2 was what I meant with heat line, but also to have a look at the PDF from Edit 3 is interesting to evaluate my data visually. I used the `SmoothHistogram` function before, but it seems that _Mathematica_ interpolates the PDF to the x-Axis. Just compare your version from Edit 2 to `SmoothHistogram[data, .02]`

Comment: @FrederikZiebell It'r true that SmoothHistogram is buggy - confirmed by Wolfram when I sent them the bug report in the post you linked originally. But in terms of comparison fo this example, are you sure you're not just seeing a different plot range? That is, try `PlotRange -> All` (MMA draws the axes not necessarily at zero)...

Answer (score 7):

Something like this would also work

```
data = {RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]};
ArrayPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["LakeColors"], 
 FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but perhaps simply this?

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
data = {#, 0} & /@ data;

Graphics[
  Raster[data\[Transpose], ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"],
  Frame -> {True, False},
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.5
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If this interpretation is correct I don't know what the purpose of `{#, 0} & /@ data` is.  Perhaps it is extraneous, and you want:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];

Graphics[
  Raster[{data}, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"], 
  Frame -> {True, False},
  PlotRangePadding -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another interpretation:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
data = {#, 0} & /@ data;

ListDensityPlot[
  data\[Transpose],
  PlotRange -> {All, {1, 1.1}}, 
  Frame -> {True, False},
  AspectRatio -> 0.02
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]