# Add a rug representation to plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, charts

This question came to me when I read [How convert list of numbers to list of points on x-axis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86440/how-convert-list-of-numbers-to-list-of-points-on-x-axis)

@Mr.W suggested [Interlacing a single number into a long list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/interlacing-a-single-number-into-a-long-list) for the question. @Artes provides a very fast way to generate the coordinates for plotting. All these remind me a widely used graph in `R`, which is called rug representation. I find *Mathematica* seems do not provide an equivalent command.

Following are three rug plots generated in `R`. The basic idea of rug is that project the data points onto an axes and represent it as thin lines beside the axes. Usually, the points will be jittered a bit off the position to avoid tiles. Using function like `Line` or `ListLinePlot` can somehow implement this function, but I do not know what is the fastest way to implement this function. Is `Line` with @Artes's solution the best choice?

[image: rug1]

[image: rug2]

[image: rug3]

### More info about rug representation

Sorry for replying messages so late! Here is more information about rug representation.

rug representation is **not a density plot**, it projects each point to the axes with a thin line. Thus, there is not bandwidth in rug representation. For dataset with tiles, the lines will be overlapped. There are two methods to get rid of this problem. One is using *opacity* to show how many lines are overlap; the other is *jitter* the coordinate a bit off the original position, then all lines are visible. The second option are used more widely. The jitter of coordinate can be set to `RandomReal[{Min[x], Max[x]},Length@x]/50`.

For the sample data, two well-known datasets from `R`: [mtcars](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/mtcars.csv) and [iris](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/iris.csv) can be used. The sample figure are plot of `wt` vs `mpg` in `mtcars`.

The start codes for the figure can be

```
mtcars = Import["mtcars.csv"];
x = Drop[mtcars[[All, 7]], 1];
y = Drop[mtcars[[All, 2]], 1];
ListPlot[Thread[List[x, y]]]
```

Comment: Please supply sample data.

Comment: It seems to me that this is better done by modifying the setting of `Ticks`/`FrameTicks` appropriately. I notice that the thickness of each "fiber" in the rug depends on how many points have the same abscissa or ordinate; `Tally[]` should be useful here in conjunction with `Thickness[]` or `AbsoluteThickness[]`.

Comment: Closely related: [One-dimensional heatmap](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8139/245)

Comment: @YvesKlett sample data is added to the question.

Comment: @Jens Sorry for late reply. rug is not a density plot, thus is not a heatmap.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. The fiber does not change the thickness. Please see the updated question. Using `Ticks`  is a interesting idea to implement rug.

Comment: Well, the overall effect of thickening would be the same as jittering, I think; the jittered lines overlap and end up looking like a single thickened line.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yes, very similar, but not exactly. I am wrapping `jitter` in `R` now. I will add it to the question soon.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that a `SmoothDensityHistogram` would be a more informative replacement for the "rug" because the superficial simplicity of the rug leads to an ambiguous, less accurate, visual representation of the information that it's supposed to convey.

Comment: The `iris` dataset is built-in: `ExampleData[{"Statistics", "FisherIris"}]`.

Comment: @Jens I thinks `rug` and `SmoothDensityHistogram` are very similar to each other, but I do not think `SmoothDensityHistogram` is always better. Density estimation usually depends on the bandwidth used, and the optimized bandwidth is another difficult task. `rug` can sometimes offer more information as shown in the middle of the third example, `rug` provide the position of data between 2.5~3.5, which is a flat line in density plot.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. using thickness is a good solution for exactly tiles. If the data is not exactly tile, the method end up with a thin line or reduce to a density estimation process.

Comment: Why go through the effort of recreating R functionality - use R-Link and call it from Mathematica...

Comment: @ciao good point.

Comment: @ciao would you please submit an answer for completeness of the possible ways to get `rug` in *Mathematica*?

Comment: @Kattern would you consider formally accepting one of the answers below, so the question will show up with an accepted answer to future searches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's generate some data to play with:

```
SeedRandom[5]
Round@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 20}], 35];
data = {#, 50 - 3 # + RandomReal[{-10, 10}]} & /@ %;
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

Here is a function that calculates the size and position of the plot "piles" and constructs the plot explicitly from graphics primitives:

```
Clear[rugplot]
rugplot[data_] := Module[
  {plotpoints, piles, listplot, plotrange, padding, ystart, yend},
  plotpoints = {PointSize[0.015], Point[data]};
  plotrange = {Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Transpose[data];
  ystart = plotrange[[2, 1]];
  yend = (plotrange[[2, 2]] - plotrange[[2, 1]])/15 + ystart;
  piles = {
      Thickness[#2/400], CapForm["Butt"],
      Line[{{#1, ystart}, {#1, yend}}]
      } & @@@ Tally[data[[All, 1]]];
  Graphics[
   {plotpoints, piles},
   PlotRange -> plotrange, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.8, Frame -> True, Axes -> False
   ]
 ]
```

We can try this out with the sample data generated above:

```
rugplot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

This is almost there, but it still needs some cosmetic adjustments to the final plot range to add some padding and more space for the bars at the bottom. Unfortunately I have to go now, so I won't be able to make the adjustments straight away, but hopefully this will help for now.

Comment: This implementation is very elegant! So the best way to do this is to use `Line` function. Am I right?

Answer (score 11):

Just to illustrate the point I made in the comment, let's take a data set where the points stack up vertically, and verify what it looks like if we visualize their density by means of a color gradient as in the question [One-dimensional heatmap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8139/245). You first have to copy the definition of `heatMap` from the second code block in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8174/245), and then execute this:

```
iris = ExampleData[{"Statistics", "FisherIris"}][[All, 1 ;; 2]];

h = Show[heatMap[Map[{#, 0} &, iris[[All, 1]]], 
    "Points" -> 2 Length[iris], "Radius" -> {1, .01}, 
    PlotRange -> {{4, 8}, {0, .1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    FrameLabel -> None, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SiennaTones"][1 - #] &)], 
   Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None, 
   AspectRatio -> Full];

ListPlot[iris, Prolog -> Inset[h, {4, 0}, {4, 0}, 4], 
 PlotRange -> {{4, 8}, {0, 4.5}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: rugreplacement]

This replacement rug is made with a color gradient (`SiennaTones`) that indicates clustering of data points by darker shading. I didn't automate the choice of plot parameters yet, but it could be done if you think it's useful. The example shows that *bandwidth is not a problem* because I use a Gaussian filter where the radius can simply be chosen to be as small as needed to achieve the maximal resolution.

**Edit**

Here is another example, where the data are distributed more irregularly:

```
mtcars = Import["mtcars.csv"];
x = Drop[mtcars[[All, 7]], 1];
y = Drop[mtcars[[All, 2]], 1];

h2 = Show[
   heatMap[Map[{#, 0} &, x], "Points" -> 10 Length[x], 
    "Radius" -> {1, .01}, PlotRange -> {{1.5, 4.5}, {0, .1}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, FrameLabel -> None, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SiennaTones"][1 - #] &)], 
   Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None, 
   AspectRatio -> Full];

ListPlot[Thread[List[x, y]], 
 Prolog -> Inset[h2, {1.5, 0}, {1.5, 0}, 3], 
 PlotRange -> {{1.5, 4.5}, {0, 40}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: rug2]

Here, I had to use more sampling points (option `"Points"`) because the data are more closely spaced in some places.

Comment: thank you for introducing me to your heat map function +1 :)

Comment: This one is good. Can you illustrate this with `mtcars` dataset as well?

Comment: @Kattern OK, I'll add that, too. The `heatMap` function I was using for convenience can probably be trimmed down and adapted to this particular task some more.

Comment: Thanks, I think this `heatMap` is pretty good. I will definitely use it for representing density estimation. Maybe I am too familiar with `rug`, I am more comfortable with reading one line as one sample. -_-. BTW, the rightmost three points are missing.

Comment: @Kattern OK - I guess I cut off the plot range too soon - but it was only meant as a proof of concept...

Comment: Yes, I understand your idea. And I personally do not like to use `rug` in figures. As I said, `rug` provides too many details, normally I do not want to show these details in the figures. However, some of my colleges like to use `rug` to show how many outliers in the figure. My point is `rug` is a little different from `density` plot.

Answer (score 9):

### "DistributionAxes" -> "Lines"

You can use `DensityHistogram` with suboption `"DistributionAxes" -> "Lines"` and `ListPlot` of the data as `Epilog`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dt = RandomReal[1, {50, 2}];

DensityHistogram[dt, Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Lines"}, 
 BaseStyle -> FaceForm[], 
 Epilog -> ListPlot[dt, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}][[1]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, with sufficiently many equal-sized bins or sufficiently small bin widths, we can use `ChartElementFunction -> "Point"` in `DensityHistogram` to get a `ListPlot` of data without using `Epilog`:

```
DensityHistogram[dt, {100, 100}, 
 Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Lines"}, ColorFunction -> (Red &), 
 ChartBaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], ChartElementFunction -> "Point"]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
dist1 = BinormalDistribution[{1, 1}, {1, 1}, 1/2];
dist2 = BinormalDistribution[{5, 5}, {1, 1}, -1/2]; dt2 = 
 RandomVariate[MixtureDistribution[{3, 2}, {dist1, dist2}], 300];
DensityHistogram[dt2, Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Lines"}, 
 BaseStyle -> FaceForm[], 
 Epilog -> ListPlot[dt2, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}][[1]]]
```

[image]

### UnivariateDataRug

```
Statistics`DataDistributionUtilities`UnivariateDataRug[dt[[All, 1]]]
```

[image]

With some processing (to remove arrows and to change orientation), the output of `` Statistics`DataDistributionUtilities`UnivariateDataRug `` can be used to construct data rugs for the vertical and horizontal axes.

```
ClearAll[rugF]
rugF[dir : ("horizontal" | "vertical") : "horizontal"] := 
  Module[{rule = If[dir === "horizontal", 
       Thread[{{x_, 0}, {x_, 1}} :> {{x, -.025}, {x, -.075}}], 
       Thread[{{x_, 0}, {x_, 1}} :> {{-.025, x}, {-.075, x}}]]}, 
    Statistics`DataDistributionUtilities`UnivariateDataRug[#] /. 
      Arrow[x_] :> {CapForm["Butt"], Line[x]} /. rule ] &;

Show[ListPlot[dt, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
 rugF["vertical"][dt[[All, 2]]], rugF[][dt[[All, 1]]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, Scaled[.02]}, {.1, Scaled[.02]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is a possible implementation of `rug` representation using `ListPlot`. Maybe implementation from @MarcoB is more efficient.

### `jitter` function

Here is a implementation of `jitter` function:

```
jitter[x_] := Module[{r, z, xx, d}, r = {Min[x], Max[x]};
  z = First@Differences[r];
  z = If[z == 0, Abs[r], z];
  z = If[z == 0, 1, z];
  xx = DeleteDuplicates@Sort@Round[x, 10^(-3 + Floor@Log10[z])];
  d = Differences[xx];
  d = If[Length@d > 0, Min@d, If[xx != 0, xx/10, z/10]];
  x + RandomReal[{-Abs[d]/5, Abs[d]/5}, Length@x]
  ]
```

Based on this, `rug` plot can be implemented as

```
ListPlot[{Thread@{x, y}, Tuples@{jitter@x, {1.5}}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{}, {"|", 6}}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: rug]

### Density plot vs. `rug`

@Jens thinks density plot is more informative. I agree with the idea that density plot are easy to read, but `rug` provides more details of the data than density estimation. Most of the time, this is a bad thing, because we do not want to represent to much information in one graph. However, I think there are cases, `rug` is more suitable. Following is density estimation and is `rug` representation of `wt` in `mtcars` dataset. I think it is not so bad to have a `rug` representation near the axes.

```
Show[{SmoothHistogram[x], 
  ListPlot[Tuples@{jitter@x, {0.02}}, PlotMarkers -> {"|", 8}]}]
```

[image: rugvsdensity]

Answer (score 4):

The solutions above don't really achieve the idea of a rug plot as it is commonly used by statisticians.  Clearly there are cases when it is not appropriate (such as on scatter plots with lots of overlapping data points), but then there are other cases (esp histograms and smooth histograms) where it is insightful (and expected by journal publishers).  But "whether to use" and "how to make" are different questions.

A standard rug plot can be achieved by using `Line` with `Scaled` offset coordinates in an `Epilog`, and setting your `PlotRangePadding` accordingly.

[image: Basic Histogram with Rug Plot]

First, here are two random datasets.

```
Data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.35, 0.05], 200];
Data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.55, 0.05], 60];
DataPoints = Flatten[{Data1, Data2}];
```

To get the rug plot you just add some extra padding to the bottom of the histogram and draw your lines in the extra space using `Epilog`.

```
Histogram[DataPoints,PlotRangePadding->{Scaled[0.02],{Scaled[0.06],Scaled[0.03]}},
Epilog->{AbsoluteThickness[0.01],Line[Table[{Scaled[{0,-0.01},{i,0}],Scaled[{0,-0.03},{i,0}]},{i,DataPoints}]]}]
```

Using this method will scale the location and heights of the plot and lines regardless of the y-scale (e.g., whether it is a PDF or a histogram of counts).  It is also easy to stack multiple sets of lines of different colors to represent multiple distributions.  You can also easily adjust the line appearance according to your preferences.