# Stacked NumberLinePlot?

Tags: plotting

Is there some built-in I can reuse to get a "stacked" number line plot? In other words, equivalent to `NumberLinePlot`, but some numbers occur more than once, so that should be reflected by stacking them.

Neither `NumberLinePlot` nor `Histogram` quite do it

```
(* visualize values of Tr(ABAAB...) for all permutations of ABAB.. *)
SeedRandom[1];
d = 3;  (* dimensions *)
s = 5; (* length of product *)
eigs1 = 1./Range[d];
eigs2 = 1./Range[d];
{b1, b2} = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[d], 2];
A = b1 . DiagonalMatrix[eigs1] . b1\[Transpose];
B = b2 . DiagonalMatrix[eigs2] . b2\[Transpose];
Clear[a, b, singleTrajectory];
singleTrajectory[s_] := RandomChoice[{a, b}, s];
sub := {a -> A, b -> B};

numSamples = 100;
orders = Table[RandomChoice[{a, b}, s], {numSamples}];
evalOrder[order_] := Log@Tr[Dot @@ (order /. sub)];
vals = evalOrder /@ orders;
NumberLinePlot[vals]
SmoothHistogram[vals]
```

[image]

[background](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442482/estimating-e-operatornametrababba-for-random-shuffling-of-a-b) on mathoverflow.SE

Comment: Maybe a rug plot?  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86568/add-a-rug-representation-to-plot

Comment: Relevant link for [DotPlot](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotPlot.html#:~:text=A%20dot%20plot%2C%20also%20called,number%20high%20for%20each%20bin.) from Wolfram MathWorld. Can't say if it is related to the Repository function by the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
stack = Join[Apply[Sequence] @ Gather @ Map[List] @ #, 2] &;

NumberLinePlot[stack @ vals, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97]@1]
```

[image]

```
Column[{%, SmoothHistogram @ vals}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, specify the `Spacings` in `NumberLinePlot` using the maximum pdf value of `SmoothKernelDistribution` of `vals` and maximum of counts to get desired vertical scaling:

```
spacings = Max[SmoothKernelDistribution[vals]["PDFValues"]]/Max[Counts @ vals]/5;

Show[SmoothHistogram @ vals, 
 NumberLinePlot[stack @ vals, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97]@2, AbsolutePointSize[3]], 
  Spacings -> spacings]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Repository function [DotPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DotPlot/), with the following usage:

```
Show[DotPlot[vals]
 , SmoothHistogram[vals]]
```

generates:

[image]

---

I had to download the source notebook and run it as `ResourceFunction` functionality is not working on my system. This function takes the same options as the `NumberLinePlot`.

Answer (score 4):

When there are not hundreds of points and few ties:

```
SmoothHistogram[vals, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[{#, 0} & /@ vals]}]
```

[image: Smooth histogram with data points]

When there are many points (irrespective of the number of ties) a strip plot using jittering gives the reader a good view of the density of points:

```
(* Generate data *)
data = Join[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100], 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 3], 200]];

(* Get smooth histogram *)
sh = SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"];

(* Get maximum vertical value from PlotRange *)
ymax = Cases[FullForm[sh], 
  Rule[PlotRange, List[List[xmin_, xmax_], List[ymin_, ymax_]]] :> ymax, Infinity][[1]];

(* Jitter the data *)
dataJittered = # + 0.05 (Max[data] - Min[data]) RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}] & /@ data;

(* Random heights *)
y = 0.05*ymax + 0.1 ymax RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, Length[data]];

(* Show resulting figure *)
Show[sh, ListPlot[Transpose[{dataJittered, y}]]]
```

[image: Smooth histogram with jittered strip plot]

Answer (score 3):

We may first count the multiplicity of every value. Then we may create a range of points with given x value and y values from 1,2,.. until the multiplicity:

```
dat = Table[{#[[1]], i}, {i, #[[2]]}] & /@ Tally[vals]
```

Finally we may plot these points:

```
ListPlot[dat]
```

[image]