# What is the best way to create a correlation matrix heatmap with values?

Tags: graphics, visualization

This may have been asked somewhere else, but I couldn't find an answer by searching. I'm trying to create a correlation table that colors the background behind the numbers as a heatmap. I've been trying to use `ArrayPlot` with `ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"`, but I'm kind of stuck.

Example:

```
data = {{1, 0., -0.8}, {0., 1, 0.}, {-0.8, 0., 1}};
ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Frame -> None, Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica at Stack exchange.  Regarding your question, it would help if you would show the code you are using for the correlation table and also the code for ArrayPlot that you tried.

Comment: Sure, this is a very simplified example but I figure I can extend a solution.

data = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1.5, 1.7, 1.2, .5}};

ArrayPlot[Correlation[data\[Transpose]], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Frame -> None, Mesh -> True]

The data is made up, but basically I want deep blue to represent -1 and red to represent 1 with gradient in between if possible.

Comment: as David told if you have the table already http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6081/how-to-create-a-heatmap-from-list-of-coordinates can be of some help to you.

Comment: I added a slightly better example to my original post, hopefully that helps. This would produce roughly what I'm looking for but with a couple of important issues. 1) the gradient isn't indexed properly (in the example -0.8 is the same as -1 in color) and 2) I'd like some way of including the values on top of the colors.

Comment: Thanks @PlatoManiac for the editing help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's do real world application. Give the members of the Dow Jones Industrial Average:

```
mem = FinancialData["^DJI", "Members"]
```

> {"AA", "AXP", "BA", "BAC", "CAT", "CSCO", "CVX", "DD", "DIS", "GE", "HD", 
>      "HPQ", "IBM", "INTC", "JNJ", "JPM", "KFT", "KO", "MCD", "MMM", "MRK", "MSFT", 
>      "PFE", "PG", "T", "TRV", "UTX", "VZ", "WMT", "XOM"}

Get monthly prices for the last 10 members for the last decade:

```
findata=FinancialData[#, "Price", {{2000}, {2010}, "Month"}][[All, 2]] & /@ mem[[-10;;-1]];
```

Find correlation matrix:

```
fincm = Correlation[Transpose@findata];
```

Overlay `Grid` over `ArayPlot` with precise `ImageSize` control:

```
Column[{
  GraphicsRow[mem[[-10 ;; -1]], ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> All],
  Row[{
    GraphicsColumn[mem[[-10 ;; -1]], ImageSize -> 50, Frame -> All],
    Overlay[{
      ArrayPlot[fincm, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][(1 + #)/2] &), 
       Frame -> None, Mesh -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
       ImageSize -> 500, ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
      GraphicsGrid[Map[NumberForm[#, 2] &, fincm, {2}], 
       ImageSize -> 500]}]
    }]}, Alignment -> Right, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

"PG" and "PFE" seem highly anti-correlated. Lets verify, indeed

```
DateListLogPlot[FinancialData[#, "Price", {{2000}, {2010}, "Month"}] & /@ {"PG", 
   "PFE"}, Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

While "XOM" and "UTX" are highly correlated, and indeed:

```
DateListLogPlot[FinancialData[#, "Price", {{2000}, {2010}, "Month"}] & /@ {"XOM", 
   "UTX"}, Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks quite close. Is there a good way to rescale the gradient so that 0. would be white(ish) and -1 (if it existed) would be the darkest shade of blue with negative numbers of blue hues and positive numbers red hues?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the image posted above but it appears that the plot is using the smallest number (-0.28) as the gradient limit which shows as a dark blue while 0.16 is showing as the most neutral (rather than values closer to 0).

Comment: @MatthewMcMaster I updated the code to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like what I was trying to do. Greatly appreciate the work!

Comment: Just wanted to add that in the `ColorFunction` you could use `Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]`. Of course its the same transformation but just for clarity sake.

Comment: @MatthewMcMaster Yes, absolutely, it is more general.

Answer (score 17):

Based on Vitaliy Kaurov's code, I would like to present another approach for making the matrix, which does not depend on `Overlay`:

```
mem = FinancialData["^DJI", "Members"];
findata = 
  FinancialData[#, "Price", {{2000}, {2010}, "Month"}][[All, 2]] & /@ 
   mem[[-10 ;; -1]];
fincm = Correlation[Transpose@findata];

tb = Map[Item[NumberForm[#, 2], 
     Background -> 
      ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]]] &, 
   fincm, {2}];
tb = Prepend[tb, mem[[-10 ;; -1]]];
tb = Join[List /@ Prepend[mem[[-10 ;; -1]], ""], tb, 2];
GraphicsGrid[tb, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> All]
```

[image: matrix]

Styling the dividers, removing the unnecessary dot after 1 and switching off the `SingleLetterItalics->True` default `Cell` option by wrapping with `Style`:

```
headings = Item[Style[#], Frame -> True] & /@ mem[[-10 ;; -1]];
tb = Map[Item[NumberForm[# /. x_ /; x == 1 -> 1, 2], Frame -> True, 
     FrameStyle -> Gray, 
     Background -> 
      ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]]] &, 
   fincm, {2}];
tb = Prepend[tb, headings];
tb = Join[List /@ Prepend[headings, ""], tb, 2];
GraphicsGrid[tb, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: matrix]