# Adding a coordinate label to individual squares in ArrayPlot[...]

Tags: plotting, graphics

Can I write text, or add a specific text label to individual squares of an ArrayPlot[...] graphic?  Specifically, I would like to assign an two-dimensional integer coordinate label to each square.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2512/121

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10519/5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be an easier way, but what about this:

```
array = RandomInteger[100, {10, 10}];
arrayPlot = ArrayPlot[array, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image: grid 1]

```
numbers = 
 Graphics[{White, 
   Table[Text[ 
      StringJoin[ToString /@ {n , ", ", m}], 
   {n - 0.5, m - 0.5}], 
   {n, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 10}]}]

Show[arrayPlot, numbers]
```

[image: grid 2]

Answer (score 4):

Coordinates in the form needed by `Part`:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 7}];

{x, y} = Dimensions @ data;

f[x_, y_, shift_] := Array[Text[{x - #2 + 1, #}, {##} - shift] &, {y, x}]

ArrayPlot[data, Epilog -> {Black, f[x, y, 0.49], White, f[x, y, 0.51]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Clever text styling! Embossing by the Boss.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
SeedRandom[1];
array = RandomInteger[100, {10, 10}];
labels = MapIndexed[
   Text[Style[
      StringTrim[ToString[#2], {"{", "}"}]
      , 10, GrayLevel[RandomReal[]]
      ]
     , #2 - 0.5] & (*end of text*)
   , array, {2}];
arrayPlot = ArrayPlot[array
  , ImageSize -> 500
  , PlotRangePadding -> 0
  , Axes -> True
  , Epilog -> { labels
    }
  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 7}];

labels = MapIndexed[Text[
    Style[Row[{1 + Dimensions[data][[1]] - #2, #} & @@ #2, ","], 
      16, If[.5 > #, Black, White]], 
    #2 - .5] &, 
  Reverse /@ Transpose[data], {2}]; 

ArrayPlot[data, Epilog -> labels, FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: It is much more readable. Thanks for the text coloring tip.