# What is the best way to draw a shaded table?

Tags: formatting, list-manipulation, rasterize

I'm trying to format a raster-style table with row and column headings and in which each cell is shaded according to the value in the cell, and the value of the cell is displayed in as text in a contrasting shade, for example

[image]

I can kludge something together that works:

```
drawTable[s_] := With[
  {
   probs = Reverse[Table[RandomReal[], {Length[s]}, {Length[s]}]]
   },
  Show[Graphics[
    Raster[
     Append[
      Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[1 - probs], Table[1, {Length[s]}]]],
       Table[1, {Length[s] + 1}]]
     ]
    ],
   Epilog -> { 
     Table[
      Text[Style[s[[i]], Bold, GrayLevel[0.2]], {0.5, 
        Length[s] - i + 0.5}], {i, Length[s]}],
     Table[
      Text[Style[s[[i]], Bold, GrayLevel[0.2]], {i + 0.5, 
        Length[s] + 0.4}], {i, Length[s]}],
     Table[ 
      {GrayLevel[If[# <= 0.5, 0, 1] &[probs[[i, j]]]], Text[
        If[# == 0 , "", #] &[Round[#, N[10^-3]] ] &[probs[[i, j]]],
        {.5 + j, -.5 + i}]
       },
      {i, Length[s]}, {j, Length[s]}]       
     }
   ]
  ]

drawTable[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "H"}]
```

But there has to be an easier way. I've arrived at positioning by quite a bit of trial and error, resulting in a quite a bit of appending, transposing and un-transposing, and tweaking of positions, and even then the result isn't perfect (for example there is extra blank space above and to the left).

Is there a better way to go about this, either strategically (what a different API) or tactically (being smarter about list handling, especially)?

---

FWIW, in the actual scenario, I need more control over the formatting of the digits and of the text used for the headings, so I expect `Text` and `Style` are needed.

Comment: Related: "[What is the best way to create a correlation matrix heatmap with values?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10519/280)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
icol[r_, c_] := Item[Style[NumberForm[r, {4,3}], c], Background -> GrayLevel[r]];
item[r_Real /; 0 <= r <= 1] := If[r > 0.5, icol[r, Black], icol[r, White]];
Grid[Map[item, RandomReal[1, {4, 4}], {2}], 
  ItemStyle -> "Text", 
  ItemSize -> {5, 5}, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

To add the row and column headers:

```
Grid[
 MapThread[
 Join,
 {{{""}, {"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}},
 Join[{{"A", "B", "C", "D"}},
  Map[item, RandomReal[1, {4, 4}], {2}]]}],
 ItemStyle -> "Text",
 ItemSize -> {5, 5},
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

Comment: And the row and column labels?

Comment: You should be able to prepend a row and column to your data (with no styling)

Comment: The shading is reverse: see the example (that's were all the `Transpose`s came from).

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid `Item` and do this by referencing the `Grid` positions directly in `Background` and `ItemStyle`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
tmp = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
```

Now:

```
Grid[tmp,
 Alignment -> {Center, Center},
 Background -> {None, None,Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 -> GrayLevel[1 - #1] &, tmp, {2}], 1]},
 ItemSize -> {10, 5},
 ItemStyle -> {None, None,Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 -> If[#1 > 0.5, White, Black] &, tmp, {2}],1]}
]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Realised I forgot to add your headers.

```
labels = {"", "A", "B", "C", "D"};

Grid[Join[List /@ labels, Join[{Rest@labels}, tmp], 2],
 Alignment -> {{Right, {Center}}, {Bottom, {Center}}},
 Background -> {None, None,Flatten[MapIndexed[1 + #2 -> GrayLevel[1 - #1] &, tmp, {2}], 1]},
 ItemSize -> {All, 5},
 ItemStyle -> {None, None,Flatten[MapIndexed[1 + #2 -> If[#1 > 0.5, White, Black] &,tmp, {2}], 1]},
 Spacings -> {{0, {3}}, {0, {3}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice factoring.

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 7;
mat = Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}], 0.01];
ft = Transpose[{Range[n], Take[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], n]}];

ArrayPlot[
 mat,
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[#1, #2 - 1/2] &, Transpose @ Reverse @ mat, {2}] /.
  Text[a_, b_] :> Text[Style[PaddedForm[a, {3, 2}], If[a > 0.5, White, Black]], b],
 FrameTicks -> {ft, ft},
 Mesh -> True,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[
 Round[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}], 0.01],
 ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit",
 Epilog -> 
  MapIndexed[Text[Framed[#1, Background -> White], #2 - 1/2] &,
   Transpose @ Reverse @ mat, {2}],
 Mesh -> True,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: If you change some ArrayPlot options (`FrameTicks -> {{ft, None}, {None, ft}}, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]`), you get an almost exact reproduction of OP's example!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to use `Graphics` and `Raster`:

```
ClearAll[rF, tF, lF];
tF = Transpose[{Range[Length@#] - 1/2,Style[#, "Panel", 18] & /@ #}] &;
(* in some versions you might need Style[#, "Panel", 18, Background -> Transparent] & *)

lF = Text[Style[#, If[# <= .5, White, Black], "Panel", 16, Background -> Transparent],#2 - 1/2] &;

rF = With[{m = N@Round[RandomReal[1, {1, 1} Length@#], 1/100]},
    Graphics[{Raster[m], MapIndexed[lF, Transpose@m, {2}]},
     Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{tF@Reverse[#], None}, {None, tF@#}}]] &;

rF@RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 7]
```

[image]

**Update:** Just in case we want colors other than `GrayLevel`

```
lF2 = Text[Style[#, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#], "Panel", 16, 
     Background -> Transparent], #2 - 1/2] &;

rF2 = With[{m = N@Round[RandomReal[1, {1, 1} Length@#], 1/100]}, 
    Graphics[{Raster[m, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], 
      MapIndexed[lF2, Transpose@m, {2}] /. 
       RGBColor -> Composition[Darker, Darker, RGBColor, Reverse[{##}] &]}, 
     Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{tF@Reverse[#], None}, {None, tF@#}}]] &;

rF2@RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 7]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) It seems that you forgot `Background -> Transparent` in the definition for `tF`: I get gray background for the tick labels without it.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thank you. Ii think this may be a version/os issue; in version 9.0.1.0 (windows 8) it works as expected as is. I will add the option to `tF`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more option using `Grid`.

```
data=Round[RandomReal[1,{5,5}],0.01];

colorIt[data_List]:=Module[{style},
    style=Item[Style[#,FontColor->ColorNegate@GrayLevel[#]],Background->GrayLevel[#]]&;
    Map[style,data,{-1}]
]

labelIt[label_List][data_List]:=Join[List/@Prepend[label,Null], Join[{label}, data], 2]

Grid[
     labelIt[{"A","B","C","D","E"}]@colorIt@data
     ,ItemSize->{4,4}
]
```

[image]