# Fix end point in smooth kernel distribution density

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I am using some extreme value fitting method which results in a parametric distribution for values exceeding some threshold, all values $\geq 0$.

For smaller values I'd like to use a smooth kernel distribution.

Pasting these two together, there is usually a small gap or jump in the distribution. So I looked for the possibility to 'fix' a point in the smoothed distribution, but found no such thing. Is there any way 'force' the smooth kernel distribution density to take a right end value?

It doesn't make a big difference, but there is simply no real reason for such a jump in the density.

Update: Of course it is possible to shift the empirical smoothed density and then scale the empirical density part to obtain a continuous density, but I am not really convinced. To me, it does not seem like the optimal solution. I'll attach two plots to illustrate the problem. 
[image]
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: Just curious how you use the `SmoothKernelDistribution` on your data and how you "paste them together". If you do this incorrectly you'll end up with a distribution that doesn't add up to a probability of 1. Could you provide a small example?

Comment: Maybe relevant: there's a bug in `SmoothKernelDistribution` that I reported, see the discussion after @rm -rf's answer to [How to create a heatmap from list of coordinates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6084/245)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: The probability of piercing the threshold is some $0<c<1$. I simply scale the empirical (smoothed) distribution so it adds up to a probability measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

Given a cut point `c` we can create a kernel density estimate `kde` truncated on `{-Infinity, c}` and a tail estimate `tail` truncated on `{c, Infinity}` with the additional restriction that the `PDF` of the tail at `c` must be equal to `PDF[kde, c]`.

To solve for this point in a way that is robust enough for a variety of data sets and distributions we need to set up special rules for dealing with likelihoods.

The function `bound` will be used to ensure that indeterminate values of the `LogLikelihood` for our restricted tail will allow optimization functions to keep searching.

```
bound[Infinity] := $MinMachineNumber 
bound[-Infinity] := $MinMachineNumber
bound[n_?NumericQ] := n
```

Now for the tail estimator. The `1000 $MachineEpsilon` is to nudge us away from restricted boundaries (and may need adjusted). The initial call to `FindDistributionParameters` attempts to get good starting values.

```
tailEstimate[dist_, data_, prob_, c_] := 
 Block[{params, est, tdist},
  params = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist];
  tdist = TruncatedDistribution[{c, \[Infinity]}, dist];
  est = Apply[
    FindMaximum, {{bound[
       LogLikelihood[tdist, Cases[data, x_ /; x > c]]], 
      DistributionParameterAssumptions[tdist] && 
       PDF[tdist, c + 1000 $MachineEpsilon] == prob}, 
     params /. Rule -> List}];
  tdist /. est[[2]]
  ]
```

Now to put it together with the kernel density estimator.

```
kde[data_, bw_, c_, tailModel_] :=
 Block[{kern, tail},
  kern = TruncatedDistribution[{-\[Infinity], c}, KernelMixtureDistribution[data, bw]];
  tail = tailEstimate[tailModel, data, PDF[kern, c], c];
  MixtureDistribution[{1, 1}, {kern, tail}]
  ]
```

Here is an example using heavy tailed data.

```
data = RandomVariate[ParetoDistribution[1, .5], 1000];
mdist = kde[data, .5, 5, ParetoDistribution[a, b]];
Plot[PDF[mdist, t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, .2}]
```

[image]