# How do I make a frequency heatmap?

Tags: plotting, data

I have an array of data that has repeats in it. I want to generate a heatmap depending on how much repetition each point has, as in how many times it is repeated.

Comment: ... and what have you tried?

Comment: It would have helped if you specified in what way you want to represent the various counts, e.g., as different colors, or as different intensities of a single color (possibly gray), and with what resolution, i.e., separation of points.

Comment: I would like it to be smooth and preferably red for high frequency and blue for low frequency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a heatmap from list of coordinates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6081/how-to-create-a-heatmap-from-list-of-coordinates)

Comment: @jens I don't think this is a duplicate, at least not if the efficient counting aspect of the question is the OP's main problem. I thinks it probably is.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries My opinion is that the question isn't specific enough to rule out that it's a duplicate, so without evidence to the contrary it's not useful to keep it open unless people want to do telepathy to answer this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tally.html) is good help in this case, it counts the number of occurances.
Using this it's easy to construct a replacement rule that replaces each element with the number of occurances, which you can then plot.

```
bd = BinomialDistribution[10, 0.4];
m = RandomVariate[bd, {100, 100}];
counts = Tally[Flatten[m]]
rule = Rule @@@ counts
ArrayPlot[m /. rule, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: ArrayPlot]

Comment: Tally and ListDensityPlot is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayPlot[# /. Rule @@@ Tally@Flatten@#] &@RandomInteger[10, {20, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Smoothing:

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {20, 20}];
f = Interpolation@Flatten[MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, # /. 
        Rule @@@ Tally@Flatten@# &@ data, {2}], 1];
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 1, 20}, {y, 1, 20}, ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
 data = RandomInteger[10, {200, 2}];
 DensityHistogram[data, 11, "Count",
 Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "BoxWhisker"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 FrameTicks -> {Thread[{Range[0.5, 10.5, 1.], ToString /@ Range[0, 10, 1]}], 
 Thread[{Range[0.5, 10.5, 1.], ToString /@ Range[0, 10, 1]}]}]
```

[image]