# ListPlot coloring by density of points

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of points on a circumference:

```
points = Map[Normalize, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3000, 2}]]
```

And I want to plot them and color the plot according to the density of points.
You see, `ListPlot[points]` will just give me that, a simple plot, on which I can't see the distribution of the points on the circle.

Maybe there is an option?

I hope you guys can understand what I'm asking.

**Edit/Follow-up**

I used `SmoothDensityHistogram[points, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`

[image: This is what it looks like]

Now, it's not really what I'm looking for. I kind of wanted it to look like the original plot, just the circumference.

Comment: I think this question is different from the linked one here: [How to create a heatmap from list of coordinates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6081/how-to-create-a-heatmap-from-list-of-coordinates) so no need to close it... But basically the answer I give to that question is also applicable here.

Comment: Thanks! I used SmoothDensityHistogram[points, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]. It's not really what I had in mind, but still does it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I think you wanted:

```
points = Map[Normalize, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3000, 2}]];

d = SmoothKernelDistribution[points];

colors = Hue /@ Rescale[PDF[d, #] & /@ points];

Graphics[Transpose[{colors, Point /@ points}]]
```

[image: pic]

Here the `SmoothKernelDistribution` is evaluated in the plane, giving you a two-dimensional interpretation of density. One could also understand your question as asking for a one-dimensional density of points only on the circle. But I followed the simplest interpretation here.

For completeness, here is an implementation using `ListPlot`. The colors are contained in `PlotStyle`, but in order to make them apply to each point individually I have to add another level of depth to the list `points`:

```
ListPlot[Map[List, points], PlotStyle -> colors, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: listPlot]

I may as well add the treatment of the density as purely one-dimensional on the circle: here I convert the elements of `points` to their polar angle coordinate, and then calculate the density in this polar angle:

```
arc = ArcTan /@ points;

d = SmoothKernelDistribution[arc];

colors = Hue /@ Rescale[PDF[d, #] & /@ arc];
```

Then proceed with the plots as above. One can of course play more with the options of `SmoothKernelDistribution`, depending on your application.

Comment: That's more like I want. A one-dimensional distribution on the circumference.

Comment: If you want this to be completely one-dimensional, you would have to convert the coordinate tuples in `points` to arc length and apply `SmoothKernelDistribution` to the result. But the logic is the same as what I did above. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I wanted.