# Implementing hexagon binning in mathematica

Tags: plotting, visualization

Hexagon bin plots are a useful way of visualising large datasets of bivariate data. Here are a few examples:

With bin frequency indicated by grey level...

[image]

..and by glyph size

[image]

There are packages for creating this kind of plot in both ["R"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/vignettes/hexagon_binning.pdf) and [Python](http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2012/dont_use_scatterplots.html). Obviously, the idea is similar to `DensityHistogram` plots.

How would one go about generating hexagonal bins in Mathematica? Also, how would one control the size of a `plotmarker` based on the bin frequency?

**Update**

As a starting point I have tried to create a triangular grid of points:

```
vert1 = Table[{x, Sqrt[3] y}, {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 10}];
vert2 = Table[{1/2 x, Sqrt[3] /2 y}, {x, 1, 41, 2}, {y, 1, 21, 2}];

verttri = Flatten[Join[vert1, vert2], 1];
```

overlaying some data..

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 20}, {500, 2}];

ListPlot[{verttri, data}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

next step might involve using `Nearest`:

```
nearbin = Nearest[verttri];

ListPlot[nearbin[#] & /@ data, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

This gives the location of vertices with nearby data points. Unfortunately, I can't see how to count those data points..

Comment: Do you know about [SmoothDensityHistogram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6081/245) - and likewise `DensityHistogram`?

Comment: MMA's `VoronoiDiagram` will be too slow for your needs.

Comment: @Jens, Yes I am aware of these functions. Not quite what I am looking for. Depending on the context I think hexagonal binning gives better representation of the data due to it's regular tessellated symmetry and nearest neighbour optimisation than a square grid.

Comment: @geordie OK - so you insist on hexbins. That means work. The bins form a **honeycomb** lattice, which is not the same as a hexagonal lattice because it's not a 2D Bravias lattice. You have to choose two Bravais lattice basis vectors and two more basis vectors for the unit cell. Then for each data point, project its coordinate on those vectors, find the integer part of the projections and count them. That will lead to the histogram count for each cell. It *doesn't* involve finding Voronoi diagrams or using `Nearest` (too slow). Don't have time to execute these steps myself...

Comment: @Jens. Yes, the question is about hexagon bin plots. What you are suggesting sounds interesting. It's a pity you don't have the time to elaborate...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With the set-up you already have, you can do

```
nearbin = Nearest[Table[verttri[[i]] -> i, {i, Length@verttri}]];
counts = BinCounts[nearbin /@ data, {1, Length@verttri + 1, 1}];
```

which counts the number of data points nearest to each vertex. Then just draw the glyphs directly:

```
With[{maxCount = Max@counts}, 
 Graphics[
  Table[Disk[verttri[[i]], 0.5 Sqrt[counts[[i]]/maxCount]], {i, Length@verttri}],
  Axes -> True]]
```

The square root is so that the *area* of the glyphs, and the number of black pixels, corresponds to the number of data points in each bin. I used `data = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{10, 10}, 7 IdentityMatrix[2]], 500]` to get the following plot:

[image]

As Jens has commented already, though, this is a unnecessarily slow way of going about it. One ought to be able to directly compute the bin index from the coordinates of a data point without going through `Nearest`. This way was easy to implement and works fine for a 500-point dataset though.

---

**Update:** Here's an approach that doesn't require you to set up a background grid in advance. We'll directly find the nearest grid vertex for each data point and then tally them up. To do so, we'll break the hexagonal grid into rectangular tiles of size $1\times\sqrt3$. As it turns out, when you're in say the $[0,1]\times[0,\sqrt3]$ tile, your nearest grid vertex can only be one of the five vertices in the tile, $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1/2,\sqrt3/2)$, $(0,\sqrt3)$, and $(1,\sqrt3)$. We could work out the conditions explicitly, but let's just let `Nearest` do the work:

```
tileContaining[{x_, y_}] := {Floor[x], Sqrt[3] Floor[y/Sqrt[3]]};
nearestWithinTile = Nearest[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {1, Sqrt[3]}}];
nearest[point_] := Module[{tile, relative},
   tile = tileContaining[point];
   relative = point - tile;
   tile + First@nearestWithinTile[relative]];
```

The point is that a `NearestFunction` over just five points ought to be extremely cheap to evaluate—certainly much cheaper than your `NearestFunction` over the several hundred points in `verttri`. Then we just have to apply `nearest` on all the data points and tally the results.

```
tally = Tally[nearest /@ data];
With[{maxTally = Max[Last /@ tally]}, 
 Graphics[
  Disk[#[[1]], 1/2 Sqrt[#[[2]]/maxTally]] & /@ tally, 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

Comment: Nice update. This is indeed *a lot* faster.

Answer (score 26):

As this answer got much more attention than I thought at first, I felt compelled to pack the answer as a function.

The following function draws three different hex-histogram representations of your data.

Code stolen liberally from the question and from Rahul's answer.

```
f[data_, cs_, ptype_] :=
 Module[{hc, vh, nearbin, counts, trr, maxCount},
  hc = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, (*hexagons positions*)
     {p, 0, 1},
     {j, 3 p/2 cs + Min[data[[All, 2]]], Max[data[[All, 2]]], 3 cs},
     {i, p Sqrt[3]/2 cs + Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]], 
      Sqrt[3] cs}], 2];

  vh = cs Vertices[Hexagon];
  nearbin = Nearest[Table[hc[[i]] -> i, {i, Length@hc}]];
  counts = BinCounts[nearbin /@ data, {1, Length@hc + 1, 1}];
  trr[v_, tr_] := Translate[Rotate[Polygon[v], Pi/2], tr];
  maxCount = Max@counts;

  Graphics[Table[
    Switch[ptype,
     1, {Opacity[counts[[n]]/maxCount], trr[vh, hc[[n]]]},
     2, trr[counts[[n]]/maxCount vh, hc[[n]]],
     3, trr[Sqrt[counts[[n]]/maxCount] vh, hc[[n]]]],
    {n, Length@hc}],
   Axes -> True]
  ]

<< Polytopes`
cs = 1/2;(*cell size*)
data = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{10, 10}, 7 IdentityMatrix[2]], 500];
GraphicsRow@Table[f[data, cs, i], {i, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### The old answer can be found in the post's edit history - removed

Comment: This is great. I have incorporated your answer into a standalone function with inputs `honeybin[xdata_, ydata_, cs_, {{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}]:=...` and the dimensions of the `verttri` array set by `Max@xdata + padding` etc. I can post it as an answer unless you want to do something similar? Also, I couldn't find a way to crop the hexagons within the axes (i also tried `Framed->True`). any suggestions? should I post what I have?

Comment: +1 that's sweet (like honey! :)). You can do it without the Polytopes package: `Hexagon[w_] := Polygon[w + N[#] & /@ (Through[{Cos, Sin}[Pi # /3]] & /@ Range[0, 6])];` then `..Rotate[Hexagon[cs] ..`.

Comment: @geordie Re: Cropping. Try with these two options combined: `PlotRange -> { {...},{...} }` and `PlotRangeClipping -> True`

Comment: @geordie I tried to make a standalone function. See if it fits you

Comment: You may want to steal from my updated answer, too... :)

Comment: @RahulNarain Yep, I saw it, thanks. But I've mainly focused on the graphical aspects, so I prefer to leave out your performance improvements so each answer has its own merits. Upvoting yours now (I forgot to do it earlier), BTW

Comment: This is super!  Also, `PlotRangeClipping` did the trick. Thanks for posting the update!

Comment: @belisarius this function is awesome but i need to use bins with unequal width and height. they'll look hexagonal with an appropriate 'AspectRatio'. is it possible to modify your function in order to do so?

Comment: @Valerio Rescale your data instead :)

Comment: On Mathematica 12.1 on Linux this produces a lot of errors and only red "error blocks" as output. Running the cell a second time (same kernel) it produces even more errors but does also output the correct figures.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a standalone function incorporating belisarius' standalone framework and Rahul Narain's *fast* use of `NearestFunction`. Full credit to these guys!

```
 Needs["Polytopes`"];
 honeybin[data_, cs_, ptype_, {{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}] :=

 (*"cs_" is the width of a bin,i.e.the distance between bin centers*)

  Module[{tileContaining, nearestWithinTile, nearest, tally, vh, hexr,
    trr},

   tileContaining[{x_, y_}] := {Floor[x], Sqrt[3] Floor[y/Sqrt[3]]};
   nearestWithinTile = 
     Nearest[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {1, Sqrt[3]}}];
   nearest[point_] := Module[{tile, relative}, tile = tileContaining[point];
   relative = point - tile;
     tile + First@nearestWithinTile[relative]];

   vh = cs 1.05 Vertices[Hexagon]/Sqrt[3];
   trr[v_, tr_] := Translate[Rotate[Polygon[v], Pi/2], tr];
   tally = Tally[cs (nearest /@ (data/cs))];

  With[{maxTally = Max[Last /@ tally]},  
   Graphics[Table[
     Switch[ptype,
      1, {Blend[{Lighter[Red, 0.99], Darker[Red, 0.6]},
         Sqrt[Last@tally[[n]]/maxTally]], trr[vh, First@tally[[n]]]},
      2, trr[Last@tally[[n]]/maxTally vh, First@tally[[n]]], 
      3, trr[Sqrt[Last@tally[[n]]/maxTally] vh, First@tally[[n]]]], 
         {n, Length@tally}], 
    Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> True]]]
```

note there is a fudge factor (`1.05`) to get rid of whitespace between the cells.

With a little Colour...

```
data = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{10, 10}, 7 IdentityMatrix[2]], 1000];
honeybin[data, 1, 1, {{1, 15}, {3, 20}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! By the way, the easiest way to do a different bin size is to divide all the data by `cs`, bin them, and then multiply the bin positions by `cs`.

Comment: @RahulNarain I just tried modifying the following: `tally = Tally[nearest /@ (data **/ cs**)];`  and `...1, {Opacity[Last@tally[[n]]/maxTally], trr[vh, **cs** First@tally[[n]]]},...etc...` is this what you meant? it gives very odd results. feel free to edit my post if you wish.

Comment: There, I fixed it. I changed the meaning of `cs` to "the width of a cell" so the original cells in the question correspond to `cs = 1`. Also, the results were no longer up to date, so I removed them; sorry if you're not happy about that.

Comment: By the way, your function doesn't work for me unless I take `<< Polytopes\`;` out of the function, but I don't know if that's me doing something wrong or what, so I haven't touched it.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks, and no worries! I didn't realise that `ClearAll["Global`*"] ` doesn't remove package definitions. I am a bit surprised that it isn't possible to 'load' a package from within a function.

Comment: You could probably also add the ability to use a custom `ColorFunction` if you're feeling charitable :)

Comment: Geordie: ``ClearAll["Global`"]`` only clears variables in the Global context, whereas your package definitions live inside its context. It is certainly possible to load a package in a function and use it immediately. With your previous definition, when you evaluate that cell, the symbols `Vertices` and `Hexagon` are created in the Global context at the parsing stage, but they're supposed to be in the Polytopes context. You could instead define them with their long forms as ``Polytopes`Vertices`` so that it is created in that context at parse time. You'll get a shadowing warning otherwise @Rah

Comment: polytopes is unnecessary if **Vertices[Hexagon]** is replaced by **CirclePoints[6]** in version 13. Thanks for the code. The speed up starts to work at 2000 points.