# How to make a function with its own options as well as passing options to other functions

Tags: functions, options, optional-arguments

I have a function with many of its own options, but I would also like to pass options to subfunctions using the `FilterRules` function.  Here's a simple example:

```
Options[pfunc] = {"test" -> True};
pfunc[x0_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{},
  Plot[x^2, {x, -x0, x0}, 
   PlotStyle -> If[OptionValue["test"], Red, Blue], 
   Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[Plot]]]]]
```

When I just try to use the options of the `pfunc` it works just fine

```
pfunc[7]
pfunc[7, "test" -> False]
```

[image]
[image]

But if I try to use an internal argument for `Plot`, it produces the figure as expected but gives error messages.

```
pfunc[7, "test" -> False, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
(*
OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option Frame for pfunc. >>

OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option Axes for pfunc. >>

OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option BaseStyle for pfunc. >>

General::stop: Further output of OptionValue::nodef will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
*)
```

[image]

Why does it give these errors?  Furthermore, what if I need to pass options to different subfunctions?

Comment: Change to `Options[pfunc] = Join[{"test" -> True}, Options[Plot]]`...

Comment: An extended example: [(358)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/358)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know why no one mentioned this, but all you have to do is to use a special form of `OptionsPattern`:

```
pfunc[x0_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[{Plot, pfunc}]] := your-code
```

where inside `OptionsPattern` go all sub-functions you need, in a list. Now everything is fine and dandy.

This has been explained already in [this answer of Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20470/function-with-custom-options-and-modified-options-for-built-in-symbols/20475#20475), so this answer and the whole question should be considered a duplicate.

There might be a downside of this, in case when several sub-functions can take the same subset of options, while you might want to pass some of the options to some sub-functions but not the other - in which case the special `"PlotOptions"` option, as suggested by rm -rf, might be a better solution. In the simple cases, however, `OptionsPattern[{f1,f2,...}]` is IMO the way to go.

Comment: This is a really nice way to do it, probably the simplest and most straightforward.  In order for `pfunc` to have its own options as well, I would include it in the list of functions, i.e. `pfunc[x0_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[{Plot,pfunc}]] :=`.  For my specific purpose, the @rm-rf allows the most precise control, but I will use this in the general case.

Comment: @JasonB You don't have to include `pfunc` in a list of functions for its own options, it is already there implicitly.

Comment: If I take the code at the very top of the post and change 'OptionsPattern[]` to `OptionsPattern[Plot]`, then I get the error message `OptionValue::optnf: Option name "test" not found in defaults for {Plot}. `  But if I change it to `OptionsPattern[{Plot,pfunc}]` then it works just fine.

Comment: Take `OptionsPattern[{Plot}]`, as in my post. I tested it, and it worked for me.

Comment: It gives the error message for me using version 9.0.0.0, 32-bit.  Unless I'm doing something wrong, here's a screenshot of the [error message](http://i.imgur.com/mxyrOBK.jpg).

Comment: @JasonB Ok, you're probably right. I must have tested this not in a fresh session, so parhaps something went wrong. I was actually surprised initially, then thought that it must've been implied.I will make a correction to the answer.

Comment: @JasonB btw, I would suggest updating to 9.0.1, which is a free update. 9.0.0 had several subtle bugs/usability issues that got fixed in the update.

Comment: I am a bit sad you didn't mention [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20475/121) but since this question seems to be a duplicate I suppose you forgot. [poke poke](http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/fighting/poking-with-stick-smiley-emoticon.gif)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I really didn't remember. Will edit this in.

Comment: lol -- thanks.  There are just too many Q&A's around here.  I'm sure I fail to cite your answers (and eBook) all the time for things I've learned, but the times I've taught *you* something are so many fewer that I like to cherish them. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I probably learned much more on SO and SE from you and others than the stuff I found out on my own or learned from other sources. Moreover, my way of learning is certainly not the most effective, because of the "find it out myself" mantra. I would've probably learn much more had I been more open to it.

Answer (score 12):

It gives those errors because you explicitly specified that `pfunc` only has `"test"` as an option. `OptionValue` is finicky and will complain if it sees options that it doesn't recognize. There are a couple of alternatives that I can think of:

#### 1: Use `FilterRules` everywhere instead of `OptionValue`

```
ClearAll@pfunc2
pfunc2[x0_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[{test = If[FilterRules[{plotopts}, "test"] === {}, True]},
        Plot[x^2, {x, -x0, x0}, PlotStyle -> If[test, Red, Blue], 
            Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[Plot]]]
        ]
    ]
```

[image]

The downside of this is that you have to pass the `plotopts` argument every time. You can fix this somewhat by defining some kind of local function as `optval = FilterRules[{plotopts}, #]&` and use that like `OptionValue`. However, by not explicitly specifying the options that your function takes, you make it harder for someone to get a summary of the function's usage by using `?`.

#### 2. Use a separate option to pass all options to `Plot`

I prefer this approach which is more verbose, but clear in intent:

```
ClearAll@pfunc3
Options@pfunc3 = {"test" -> True, "PlotOptions" -> {}};
pfunc3[x0_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{},
  Plot[x^2, {x, -x0, x0}, 
   PlotStyle -> If[OptionValue["test"], Red, Blue], 
   Evaluate@OptionValue["PlotOptions"]]]
```

[image]

You can add additional checks to make sure that only valid options are being passed to `Plot`, but you get the idea. The added advantage is that this is easily extendable to more complex scenarios. For instance, suppose you have a type of plot that has a grid of `Plot`, `Graphics` and a `DensityPlot`. What do you do with the first approach if you want to pass different options to each of those? It's not going to be easy, since they all accept `Frame`, `PlotStyle`, `Mesh` etc. With this approach, you can group the options as `"PlotOptions" -> {...}, "DensityPlotOptions" -> {...}, "GraphicsOptions" -> {...}` and so on.

Comment: That last method is perfect, thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

I believe you need to add all of `Plot`'s options to `pfunc` as well, like this:

```
Options[pfunc] = Join[ Options[Plot], {"test" -> True, ...} ]
```

I'd like to note that this is what builtins do as well.  For example, `Plot` also carries all possible `Graphics` options.  The downside is that any changes to the default options of `Plot` won't affect `pfunc`.  The upside is that it *will* be possible to change the defaults on `pfunc`, and also that you get error reporting about invalid options for free.

There are some other things worth correcting: while `Plot` and `Graphics` accept options grouped into a list, as in `Plot[..., {Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red}]`, many other functions don't.

So I'd write the function like this:

```
pfunc[x0_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{seq = Sequence @@ FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[Plot]]},
  Plot[x^2, {x, -x0, x0}, seq, PlotStyle -> If[OptionValue["test"], Red, Blue]]
 ]
```

I also moved `seq` before your own `PlotStyle` option, to make the `PlotStyle` overridable.

Well, this is [how I usually do it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42662/12), but since I don't have a lot of experience with options handling, I'm not sure it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, but I don't think it's the most elegant solution available.  Basically, I separate the `Plot` options from the `pfunc` options via curly brackets, like this:

```
Options[pfunc] = {"test" -> True};
pfunc[{x0_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{},
  Plot[x^2, {x, -x0, x0}, 
   PlotStyle -> If[OptionValue["test"], Red, Blue], 
   Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[Plot]]]]]
pfunc[{7, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> 20}, 
 "test" -> False]
```

This produces the same plot as above without any error messages.

This is a fine workaround, but sometimes you want to pass options to different subfunctions.  This is what I've been able to come up with, but it feels like there should be a better way:

```
Options[pfunc2] = {"test" -> True};
pfunc2[{x0_, 
   plotopts : OptionsPattern[]}, {plotopts2 : OptionsPattern[]}, 
  OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{p1, p2},
  p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -x0, x0}, 
    PlotStyle -> If[OptionValue["test"], Red, Blue], 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[Plot]]]];
  p2 = Plot[x^3, {x, -x0, x0}, 
    PlotStyle -> If[OptionValue["test"], Red, Blue], 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts2}, Options[Plot]]]];
  Grid[{{p1, p2}}]]


pfunc[{7, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  BaseStyle -> 20}, {Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300}]
```

[image]

```
pfunc2[{7, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> 20}, {}, 
 "test" -> False]
```

And then if you don't want to pass any options you do it like this:

```
pfunc2[{7}, {}]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems weird to answer my own question, but I've been told before that this is acceptable.  I have a solution, I just want to see if there is a better one, where I don't have to put in the empty curly brackets like in the last line.