# how to make a customized plotting function that can accept Mathematica's built-in optional arguments?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, options

Suppose I have the following plotting function:

```
selfPlot[func_]:=Show[ContourPlot[Re[f[x+I*y]],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}],ContourPlot[Im[f[x+I*y]],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]]
```

How can I modify the function so that it can accept optional arguments like `ContourStyle`, `AspectRatio` that can be passed into the built-in `ContourPlot`?

Comment: Take a look at `OptionsPattern`, `FilterRules` and many related topics here.

Comment: See the examples [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43088/9490) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20470/9490)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `BlankNullSequence` to deal with the options, just like this following code

```
selfPlot[f_, opts___] := 
 ContourPlot[{Re[f[x + I*y]], Im[f[x + I*y]]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   opts]
selfPlot[#^2 Sin[#] &, ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```