# Is this the correct method for using optional arguments?

Tags: optional-arguments

I've read [this page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html) but I'm still kind of confused about something. Here's a simple example function, where it simply plots a function. If you give it the ImageSize option, it should use that, but otherwise it should use the default one of ImageSize->100:

```
Options[PlotWrapperFn] = {ImageSize -> 100};
PlotWrapperFn[pTitle_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := (
  Print@Style[pTitle, 24];
  Return@Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]];
  )
```

As I understand it, the line with `FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]` is essentially taking the options out of `opts` that are valid options for `Plot[]` and using them with `Plot[]`.

However, it became clear to me that this doesn't work, because if you call the function without the `ImageSize` option, `opts` is empty and thus it doesn't add any options to `Plot`.

If I instead make it filter the options for `PlotWrapperFn` by doing `Evaluate[FilterRules[{Options[PlotWrapperFn]}, Options[Plot]]]`, it will obviously always choose the default option of `ImageSize->100`, defeating the purpose of making it an option.

I realized I can do it by using `Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts,Options[PlotWrapperFn]}, Options[Plot]]]`, because that searches both opts and Options[PlotWrapperFn] and finds an ImageSize rule in each, but uses the first one it sees, from opts.

Is that the correct way? It seems weird to pass the option twice and rely on it using the first one.

Another way I figured out is to do:

```
rules = (# -> OptionValue[#]) & /@ (Options[PlotWrapperFn][[All, 1]]);
Return@Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, Evaluate@rules];
```

Which basically manually lists the current value of the option, not what was passed to the function (like `opts`) or in the default list (like `Options[PlotWrapperFn]`).

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. How do people do this?

Comment: Are you only going to use `Plot` options, or will there be other options that do not belong to `Plot`?

Comment: @JasonB, let's definitely assume that there will be other options that don't apply to Plot[].

Comment: Okay, I think this may be a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43088/9490), but maybe not.  Here there is the complication that you want to define default options for `Plot` within your function.  I tried to handle that in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

What I like to take advantage of is that you can pass the same option multiple times, and only the first `OptionValue` is used.  So you can include the default in your plot command, but precede it by `opts`:

```
Options[PlotWrapperFn2] = {"TitleSize" -> 24};
PlotWrapperFn2[pTitle_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{Plot, PlotWrapperFn2}]] := (Print@
   Style[pTitle, OptionValue["TitleSize"]];
  Return@Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]], ImageSize -> 100];)
```

So if `opts` contains a `ImageSize` option, it will override the default

```
PlotWrapperFn2["hello"]
PlotWrapperFn2["hello", ImageSize -> 400, "TitleSize" -> 13]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also used the formatting for the options pattern described in Leonid's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43114/9490)