# Plot density of discrete data

Tags: plotting, cluster-analysis

I have some discrete data in the form `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` and when I produce a `ListLogLogPlot` they look like this:

[image: 2D discrete data]

I would like to produce a density plot or map saying, how much packed the points are (I am not really sure, how this should be achieved though, my first idea is take a circle of a fixed radius centered on a given point and count how many neighbours there are and based on that assign value/colour but maybe this is nonsense). I found the most likely candidate to be `SmoothDensityHistogram` but it produces this (I admit, I do not understand this function much, I read help, but there everything works perfectly however they generate the data syntetically):

[image: SmoothDensityHistogram result]

But if I look at the first plot, quite obviously the plot I want should look like "a hot area in the center with tails to the north and east". There is an ovious another issue, how to force log scales to `SmoothDensityHistogram`, because when I use

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[smbdataSpin[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 0.1, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {Log, Log}]
```

I get something even more strange:

[image: SmoothDensityHistogram result with log scaling]

The data that produce the first plot can be obtained [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4b4tXLBYQT9SHliUDBPTFE4LW8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you looked at [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot)?

Comment: @CarlWoll I know of it but unless I am missing something, that constructs the density from the values of the array which in my case makes little sense I think because e.g. `{{1,1},{2,2}}` would have the highest value of density in the top right corner but that is incorrect as it says nothing about the density of points in the plot.

Comment: My bad. I think that `SmoothDensityHistogram` should work, but there seems to be an issue with the `ScalingFunctions` option.

Comment: If the set of points is a simple random sample from a bivariate probability distribution, you should try `SmoothKernelDistribution[smbdataSpin[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]`.

Comment: Another approach is hexagon binning:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28149/implementing-hexagon-binning-in-mathematica.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly the following is what you're looking for?

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[
    Log @ data,
    Frame->True,
    PlotRange->All,
    FrameTicks -> {
        {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]},
        {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this in 3D

```
ticks = {
    Table[{n, 10^n}, {n, -3, 3}],
    Table[{n, 10^n}, {n, -2, 3}],
    Automatic} /. r_Rational :> N[r];

Histogram3D[Log10[data],
 Ticks -> ticks,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][height]]]
```

[image]

```
SmoothHistogram3D[Log10[data],
 Ticks -> ticks,
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, height}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][height]]]
```

[image]