# Plotting correlation between two metrics that contain hundreds of thousands of data points

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, python, correlation, jupyter-notebook

I wanted some feedback on what is thought of as best practice in terms of showing correlation between two metrics in terms of minutes vs minutes when both metrics contain a large amount of data points ( hundreds of thousands or low millions trying to avoid a scatter plot with too many data points making it unreadable.

Thanks!

Comment: [Density histograms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityHistogram.html) are great for this. Please give an example data set with a small number of points, so that we can be sure what you mean, and propose concrete solutions.

Comment: Along the same lines, er, shapes that @Roman suggests is hexagon binning:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28149/implementing-hexagon-binning-in-mathematica.

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the response, adding example data now, is it possible to chart density histograms in Python/pandas?

Comment: @Chris you'll have to go elsewhere to ask about Python/pandas. This forum is about *Mathematica*.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "matrices" where you wrote "metrics"?