# Show density plot on a geographic map

Tags: plotting, geography

I have a bunch of data points in the form of `{latitude, longitude}`. How can I plot their density on a US map? Single points on the map do not clearly show their distribution, so I'd like it to be a density map or something clearer. Please suggest.

---

*Note from [Vitaliy Kaurov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13/vitaliy-kaurov)*: this subject is also applicable to any geographic map (not necessarily US) and also to contour plots and general heat maps (besides density plots).

Comment: Maybe [SmoothDensityHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothDensityHistogram.html)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Update (15 FEB 2017)

In the light of new geo-functionality developments I would like to add another approach via **GeoImage**. Consider the magnitude of the geomagnetic field across the entire planet. Get the data:

```
data = QuantityMagnitude[
   GeomagneticModelData[{{-90, -180.}, {90, 180.}}, "Magnitude", 
    GeoZoomLevel -> -2]];
```

Build high-res contour plot:

```
plot = ListContourPlot[data, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Frame -> False, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2, ImageSize -> 800, Contours -> 20, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.2]]
```

[image]

Specify how you would like to place this rectangle on the map (we use world range to show the application of geo-projection too):

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", plot}, 
   GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-180, 180}}], Opacity[0.6], 
  GeoBoundsRegion["World"]}, GeoRange -> "World", 
 GeoProjection -> "Robinson"]
```

[image]

Colored background interferes with colors of the heat map. Use just coastlines:

```
GeoGraphics[{
  GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", plot}, 
   GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-180, 180}}], Opacity[.8], 
  GeoBoundsRegion["World"]}, GeoRange -> "World", 
 GeoProjection -> "Robinson", GeoBackground -> 
{"Coastlines", "Land" -> White, "Ocean" -> White, "Border" -> Black}]
```

[image]

## Older versions

Well I do not have your data, so I'll just show things I have. I'll go with India, it has nice cities layout. You can upgrade for your data yourself. If you know only locations of cities, but **not** their population, then

```
data = DeleteCases[
   Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ CityData[{All, "India"}], 
Missing["NotAvailable"]];

Show[SmoothDensityHistogram[data, .3, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
   PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.1], PlotRange -> All], 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Directive[White, Opacity[.7]]], 
   CountryData["India", "Polygon"]}]]
```

[image]

If you know the population, then maybe something like this:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.1, Blue], 
  Cases[Disk[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]], 
      Log[10.^12, CityData[#, "Population"]]] & /@ 
    CityData[{All, "India"}], Disk[{__Real}, _Real]], {FaceForm[], 
   EdgeForm[Directive[Red, Thick, Opacity[.9]]], 
   CountryData["India", "Polygon"]}}, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

For US use something like:

```
data = DeleteCases[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ 
    CityData[{All, "UnitedStates"}], Missing["NotAvailable"]];
Show[SmoothDensityHistogram[data, .5, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
   PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.1], PlotRange -> All], 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Directive[White, Opacity[.7]]], 
   CountryData["UnitedStates", "FullPolygon"]}], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-180, -65}, {20, 70}}, 
 ImageSize -> 800, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: @VitallyKaurov nice answer. It's nice to state that SmoothDensityHistogram has an undesired deslocation as you can see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6082/2266). You can see it in your first plot using `PointSize[Tiny],White,Point[data]`

Comment: One option is to use `{0.3, {"Radial","Gaussian"}},"PDF"` in `SmoothDensityHistogram`

Comment: I wonder why this does not work for US map. `data = DeleteCases[
   Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ 
    CityData[{All, "UnitedStates"}], Missing["NotAvailable"]];

Show[SmoothDensityHistogram[data, .3, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
   PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.1], 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Directive[White, Opacity[.7]]], 
   CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"]}]]`

Comment: @QiangLi See update at the end.

Comment: In Mathematica 10, you will need this for the second example: QuantityMagnitude@CityData[#, "Population"] (because CityData now returns with a unit)

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, it'd be great if you would also post about the new [GeoSmoothHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoSmoothHistogram.html) and maybe [GeoHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoHistogram.html). It's great to see how WL is evolving to solve more and more problems easily...

Answer (score 23):

Due to the limitations on the accuracy of `SmoothKernelDistribution` (mentioned by Murta) upon which `SmoothDensityHistogram` is based, I prefer to work with the more exact `KernelMixtureDistribution`.

I will use the same data as Vitaliy here.

```
data = DeleteCases[
   Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ CityData[{All, "India"}], 
   Missing["NotAvailable"]];
```

Note the use of `MaxMixtureKernels` -> `All`.  This ensures that each data point will have a kernel placed at it.  If we don't do this `KernelMixtureDistribution` may use a binned estimator.

```
dens = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, MaxMixtureKernels -> All];
```

For some added value credit goes to @rm-rf for pointing out the following [point-in polygon algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/5).  Note that it does not work for polygons with multiple components so we will need to table over those.

```
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[poly, pt];
```

Lets obtain the polygon data for India...

```
poly = CountryData["India", "Polygon"][[1]];
```

And now to display the density (I prefer the use of `ContourPlot` but we could just as easily have used `DensityPlot`). I use `Table` here so that we account for the small islands to the south east of the mainland.

```
p1 = ContourPlot[Evaluate@PDF[dens, {x, y}], {x, 65, 100}, {y, 0, 40},
       PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
       PlotPoints -> 100, RegionFunction -> (inPolyQ[poly[[1]], {#1, #2}] &), 
       PlotLegends -> Automatic];

Show[p1, Table[
       ContourPlot[Evaluate@PDF[dens, {x, y}], {x, 65, 100}, {y, 0, 40}, 
         PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
         PlotPoints -> 100, RegionFunction ->(inPolyQ[i, {#1, #2}] &)], {i,Rest@poly}], 
       Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], CountryData["India", "Polygon"]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to reproduce your work with MMA 11.1, but encounter this:
ContourPlot::invregion: (inPolyQ[poly[[1]],{#1,#2}]&)[Identity[#1],Identity[#2],Identity[#3]]& must be a Boolean function.

Answer (score 16):

Here's just a different suggestion. Playing around with the parameters can yield very different results, so it's encouraged.

I'm using the same data as Vitaliy:

```
data = DeleteCases[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ CityData[{All, "India"}], Missing["NotAvailable"]];
outline = ColorNegate@Graphics[CountryData["India", "Polygon"]];
```

My solution plots each point as a disk and then blurs them together, hence creating a heat map.

```
density[data_, r_] := Blur[Graphics[Disk[#, 0.1] & /@ data], r];
map[outline_, density_, col_] := ImageCrop@ImageMultiply[ ImageApply[(ColorData[col]@Mean[#] &@#) /. RGBColor[r_, g_, b_] :> {r, g, b} &, density], outline];
```

Examples:

```
map[outline, density[data, 20], "SunsetColors"]
```

[image: map1]

```
map[outline, density[data, 5], "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image: map2]

If you want a different background you can replace `ImageMultiply` by `SetAlphaChannel` and then use for example `Show[myMap,Background->Blue]`. It is possible to add a border using `EdgeDetect`, which can be put on top of the image. `Dilation` can be used to adapt the width of the border.

**EDIT**

Creating these charts seem to require some manual changing of the plot range for certain polygons (depending on how `CountryData` specifies them, I suppose). I honestly thought the above would always work. I tried making a general approach by setting `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding` explicitly, and this worked but the solution is not very short anymore (though this partly depends on a few new options, like borders, that I added).

```
Options[densityMap] = {diskSize -> 1, blurRadius -> 10, padding -> 10,
    background -> Black, showBorder -> False, borderMagnify -> 0, 
   borderColor -> Black};
densityMap[country_, data_, col_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{plotrange, disks, density, outline, outlineObj, border, 
   rendered},
  outlineObj = 
   Graphics[{White, CountryData[country, "Polygon"]}, 
    Background -> OptionValue[background], 
    PlotRangePadding -> OptionValue[padding]];
  outline = Rasterize[outlineObj];
  plotrange = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[outlineObj];
  disks = Graphics[{
     Disk[#, OptionValue[diskSize]] & /@ data
     }, PlotRange -> plotrange, 
    PlotRangePadding -> OptionValue[padding]];
  density = SetAlphaChannel[
    SetAlphaChannel[
     ImageApply[(ColorData[col]@Mean[#] &@#) /. 
        RGBColor[r_, g_, b_] :> {r, g, b} &, 
      ColorNegate@Blur[disks, OptionValue[blurRadius]]], 
     ColorNegate@Blur[disks, OptionValue[blurRadius]]],
    Graphics[{White, CountryData[country, "Polygon"]}, 
     Background -> Black, PlotRangePadding -> OptionValue[padding]]
    ];

  If[OptionValue[showBorder],
   border = 
    Dilation[
     EdgeDetect[
      Graphics[{White, CountryData["United States", "Polygon"]}, 
       Background -> Black, 
       PlotRangePadding -> OptionValue[padding]]], 
     OptionValue[borderMagnify]];
   rendered = 
    SetAlphaChannel[
     ImageAdd[ColorConvert[ColorNegate@border, "RGB"], 
      OptionValue[borderColor] /. RGBColor[r_, g_, b_] :> {r, g, b}], 
     border];
   Show[outline, density, rendered],
   Show[outline, density]
   ]

  ]
```

Using the OP suggested:

```
data = Reverse /@ {CityData[{"New York City", "USA"}, "Coordinates"], 
    CityData[{"Boston", "Massachusetts", "USA"}, "Coordinates"]} ;

densityMap["United States", data, "SunsetColors", blurRadius -> 5, 
 diskSize -> 1, background -> White]
```

Unfortunately this method introduces white artifacts, which I believe are due to a bug in `ImageApply`. For that reason this function works best with either a white background or one can use the border option which will cover them up. See the beginning of the code for the list of options.

[image: improved]

Comment: Very nice, and it even runs in version 7. +1

Comment: A very interesting way to implement radially symmetric uniform kernels +1.

Comment: `data={CityData[{"New York City", "USA"}, "Coordinates"],CityData[{"Boston", "Massachusetts", "USA"},"Coordinates"]}
outline=ColorNegate@
   Graphics[CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Shape", "Equirectangular"}]];

outline = Graphics[CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Shape", "Mercator"}]];density[data_, r_] := Blur[Graphics[Disk[#, 0.1] & /@ data], r];map[outline_, density_, col_] := 
  ImageCrop@ImageMultiply[
    ImageApply[(ColorData[col]@Mean[#] &@#) /.RGBColor[r_, g_, b_] :> {r, g, b} &, density], outline];map[outline, ImageRotate[density[data, 1], 0], "SunsetColors"]` Please take a look.

Comment: hi Anon, I tried with the above code on US map, but it does not locate the cities correctly. Please help take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @QiangLi You've made a few changes; e.g. not reversing the coordinates, not requesting the polygon but the shape, adding `ImageRotate`. But still even if you do everything right you might have to make some adjustments because of problems with the plot range. I will look into this later.

Comment: @Anon, Please. I think I changed the non-essential part, in particular, the rotate is 0 degree. What do you mean by reverse the coordinates though? :)

Comment: @QiangLi Almost got an answer for you now. I just pointed out what I saw, you may be right. You have to reverse coordinates like Vitaliy did: `Reverse/@data` (data is lat, long instead of long, lat to being with)

Comment: Even I did Reverse/@data, it still does not help. The map seems to be on a different scale than the lat/long.

Comment: Yes, the plot range is messed up. I've written a function now that'll work for anything, but it was a lot more painful to solve this problem in general than to solve it for a specific country hehe. I'm starting to feel like I should've just done the US to start with :)

Comment: @QiangLi OK, there's a new version up. It's kind of sad that the first neat solution doesn't always work, and entirely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possibility. The trouble with the use of either `SmoothKernelDistribution[]` or `KernelMixtureDistribution[]` is that neither of the two distributions take into account that the data are, well, points on a sphere! (Fine, more or less a sphere... :P)

In this [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14020), I illustrated the "spherical smooth histogram" function from [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0098-3004(85)90015-9); among other things, the function will not suffer from boundary problems if, say, one wants to study the islands clustered around the International Date Line.

Only a few modifications are needed so that the density function is expressed in terms of longitude/latitude:

```
(* U.S. outline *)
uspoly = Reverse /@ First[CountryData["UnitedStates", "Coordinates"]];

(* some cities *)
uscities = Select[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ 
                  CityData[{Large, "UnitedStates"}], FreeQ[#, _Missing] &];
(* unit vectors *)
cityVecs = {Cos[#1] Cos[#2], Sin[#1] Cos[#2], Sin[#2]} & @@@ (uscities °);

(* "robust" estimate of smoothing parameter *)
c1 = (Length[cityVecs]^(1/3) (Length[cityVecs] - 1))/
     Total[ArrayPad[Drop[Sort[1 - cityVecs.Normalize[Total[cityVecs]]], -2],
                    {0, 2}, "Fixed"]];

(* smoothing parameter, automatically determined by maximizing "pseudo-log likelihood" *)
(* as a conservative estimate, the larger of the "pseudo-log likelihood" estimate
   and "robust" estimate is chosen *)
c = Max[c1,
        With[{n = Length[cityVecs]}, First @ FindArgMax[
             Sum[Log[Total[\[FormalC] Csch[\[FormalC]] Exp[\[FormalC]
                           Delete[cityVecs, k].Extract[cityVecs, k]]/
                           (4 π (n - 1))]], {k, n}], {\[FormalC], c1}, 
             Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]]];

(* spherical smooth density histogram *)
With[{n = Length[cityVecs]}, 
     DensityPlot[Total[c Csch[c] Exp[c cityVecs.
                       {Cos[λ °] Cos[ϕ °], Sin[λ °] Cos[ϕ °], Sin[ϕ °]}]/(4 π n)],
                 {λ, -130, -60}, {ϕ, 20, 50},
                 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors",
                 Mesh -> True, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
                 PlotPoints -> 95, PlotRange -> All, 
                 RegionFunction -> (Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ[uspoly,
                                                                     {#1, #2}] &)]]
```

[image: spherical smooth density histogram]

---

As another demonstration, here is a smooth histogram of the capital cities of the world:

```
capitals = Select[Reverse[CityData[CountryData[#, "CapitalCity"], "Coordinates"]] & /@ 
                  CountryData[], FreeQ[#, _Missing] &];
cVecs = {Cos[#1] Cos[#2], Sin[#1] Cos[#2], Sin[#2]} & @@@ (capitals °);

(* smoothing parameter *)
c1 = (Length[cVecs]^(1/3) (Length[cVecs] - 1))/
     Total[ArrayPad[Drop[Sort[1 - cVecs.Normalize[Total[cVecs]]], -2],
                    {0, 2}, "Fixed"]];
c = Max[c1, 
        With[{n = Length[cVecs]}, First @ FindArgMax[
             Sum[Log[Total[\[FormalC] Csch[\[FormalC]] Exp[\[FormalC] Delete[
          cVecs, k].Extract[cVecs, k]]/(4 π (n - 1))]], {k, n}],
          {\[FormalC], c1}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]]];

hist = With[{n = Length[cVecs]}, Image[DensityPlot[
             Total[c Csch[c] Exp[c cVecs.
                   {Cos[λ °] Cos[ϕ °], Sin[λ °] Cos[ϕ °], Sin[ϕ °]}]/(4 π n)],
             {λ, -180, 180}, {ϕ, -90, 90}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
             ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", Frame -> False, Mesh -> True,
             MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ImagePadding -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
             PlotPoints -> 95, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
            ImageResolution -> 300]];

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[λ °] Cos[ϕ °], Sin[λ °] Cos[ϕ °], Sin[ϕ °]},
                 {λ, -180, 180}, {ϕ, -90, 90}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                 Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[hist],
                 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)]
```

[image: spherical smooth histogram of capital cities]

---

For some reason, the performance of this method is rather slow for Vitaliy's India example; I'll do more research on how to make this method more efficient.